# How to use chosen's max_selected_options as dynamic value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, jquery-chosen

I am using [chosen](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/) library in my Web Application. I have set the `max_selected_options` as 4.

Here's my code:-

```
$('#tag').chosen({max_selected_options:4});
$('#tag').bind("chosen:maxselected", function() {
    var htmlMSG = '<strong>Severe Error!</strong><p>You can only add 4 tags.</p>';
    $('#modalSuccess').html('');
    $('#modalError').html('');
    $('#modalError').html(htmlMSG);
    $('#modalError').show();
    $('#modalSuccess').hide();
    $('#modal_redirect').val('false');   
    $('#modal').modal('show'); 
});
```

Now, in the code, I am using:-

```
var htmlMSG = '<strong>Severe Error!</strong><p>You can only add 4 tags.</p>'
```

where I have set the message showing `4` as *hard-coded*.

Is there any way where I can use dynamic value in the HTML Message?
Say, is there something like

```
var htmlMSG = '<strong>Severe Error!</strong><p>You can only add '+ chosen.max_selected_options +' tags.</p>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Would a basic variable work for you here? Still fairly hardcoded, but in your example max_selected_options seems to be hardcoded at 4 as well, not sure if the rest of your code is a little more complicated/dynamic than this.

```
var maxSelect = 4;

$('#tag').chosen({max_selected_options:maxSelect});
$('#tag').bind("chosen:maxselected", function() {
    var htmlMSG = '<strong>Severe Error!</strong><p>You can only add' + maxSelect + 'tags.</p>';
    $('#modalSuccess').html('');
    $('#modalError').html('');
    $('#modalError').html(htmlMSG);
    $('#modalError').show();
    $('#modalSuccess').hide();
    $('#modal_redirect').val('false');   
    $('#modal').modal('show'); 
});
```

For something possibly more dynamic, you could use data attributes if you have access to the DOM:

```
$('.select_input').each(function(){
    var maxSelect = $(this).data('selectmax');

    $(this).chosen({max_selected_options:maxSelect});
    $(this).bind("chosen:maxselected", function() {
        var htmlMSG = '<strong>Severe Error!</strong><p>You can only add' + maxSelect + 'tags.</p>';
        $('#modalSuccess').html('');
        $('#modalError').html('');
        $('#modalError').html(htmlMSG);
        $('#modalError').show();
        $('#modalSuccess').hide();
        $('#modal_redirect').val('false');   
        $('#modal').modal('show'); 
    });
});
```

and HTML:

```
<select data-selectmax="4" class="select_input">...</select>
```

Comment: I have thought about that. But Different select boxes would have different max_selected_options. Later based on specific max_select_options I will need to write some conditional code. That's why I would like to know if there is any way to detect the max_selected_options

Comment: Updated my code, not sure if data-attributes is a possibility for you here.